# Axios post works, Axios put doesn't get past preload request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, axios

Axios put won't get past preload request, but if I change it to post, the request does send.

This is my code. In the network tab OPTIONS shows, but on post, it sends OPTIONS and POST.

```
handleSubmit() {
                axios.put(process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE + 'auth/password', {
                  password: this.password,
                  password_confirmation: this.password_confirmation,
                  current_password: this.current_password
                })
            }
```

What could be causing the PUT request to not send?

For both PUT and POST, the OPTIONS request returns code 200

Comment: The option request is successful but the actual put request doesn't. The options is just for the CORS request.

Answer (score 1):

Check your OPTIONS response.
Most likely PUT is missing from the list of accepted method requests. Check the **Access-Control-Request-Method** header values.

More about access control request methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Method)

Comment: The request requests the method PUT and the response body is empty.